# Socket.IO Cluster with nginx load balancer issues

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I am running NGINX as a reverse proxy for a Socket.IO server that load balances requests accross multiple cluster processes. Each of the cluster processes are told to listen on different ports.

The nginx server is configured to load balance based on IP hash but I get the message:

`ws://{domain}/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=KaU3C8caGVK4gU1LAAAB failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

My nginx config has:

```
http {
    {+ default configs}

    upstream io_nodes {
        ip_hash;
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
        server 127.0.0.1:3002;
        server 127.0.0.1:3003;
    }

}
```

default vhost:

```
server {
#listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
#listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

root /usr/share/nginx/www/static/web;
index index.html index.htm;

# Make site accessible from http://localhost/
server_name {domain};

location / {
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://io_nodes;
     }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. If I run the nodejs server without cluster it behaves correctly, the reference that I used for this set up is found at: http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue was that the version of nginx installed was < 1.3 and did not have websockets support.

For anyone else you can check out how to install a newer version of nginx on ubuntu from:

http://usefulmix.com/install-upgrade-to-latest-nginx-without-compiling-from-source/